# Using a function inside gsub in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have

```r
txt <- "{a} is to {b} what {c} is to {d}"
key <- c(a='apple', b='banana', c='chair', d='door')
fun <- function(x) key[x]
```

and I would like to quickly convert `txt` according to `key` into:

```r
"apple is to banana what chair is to door"
```

I know I can repeatedly use `gsub` (or something similar) like this:

```r
for (v in names(key)) txt <- gsub(sprintf('{%s}',v), fun(v), txt, fixed = TRUE)
txt
# [1] "apple is to banana what chair is to door"
```

but my `txt` and `key` are very long, so the above is problematic. I would like to know if there are faster methods like:

```r
gsub(sprintf('{%s}',names(key)), key, fixed = TRUE) # Does not work
gsub('\\{(a|b|c|d)\\}', fun(...), txt, fixed = TRUE) # Does not work
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could use `glue` after creating the elements of key as objects

```
list2env(as.list(key), .GlobalEnv)
glue::glue(txt)
```

-output

```
apple is to banana what chair is to door
```

---

If we don't want to create objects in the global env, an option is also to add the `key[` with `gsub` inside the `{}` and then use `glue`

```
glue::glue(gsub("\\{([^}]+)\\}", "{key['\\1']}", txt))
apple is to banana what chair is to door
```

Or as @Robert Hacken mentioned in the comments, the `.envir` would be more compact

```
glue::glue(txt, .envir=as.list(key))
apple is to banana what chair is to door
```

Comment: `glue` has an `.envir` argument, so how about `glue(txt, .envir=as.list(key))`?

Answer (score 5):

With `glue_data()`:

```
library(glue)
glue_data(key, txt)
# apple is to banana what chair is to door
```

Raw example of using Python within R:

```
library(reticulate)
list2env(as.list(key), envir = .GlobalEnv)
py_run_string('res = f"{r.a} is to {r.b} what {r.c} is to {r.d}"')
py$res
# "apple is to banana what chair is to door"
```

Answer (score 4):

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` except the replacement string can be a key/value named list or function (or proto object).  We show using each of those two below.  The capture group in the regular expression is input into the key/value pair as the key or function as argument and the value or function output replaces the entire match.

```
library(gsubfn)

# key/value list
gsubfn("{(\\w+)}", as.list(key), txt)
## [1] "apple is to banana what chair is to door"

# function
gsubfn("{(\\w+)}", fun, txt)
## [1] "apple is to banana what chair is to door"
```

Regarding the comment, if the input can have {...} constructs that do not correspond to any key in key then to preserve such text without change use one of these. The first modifies the function to return the input if there is no match to any key.  The second puts brace brackets around the keys in key so that non-keys have no match.  The last one changes the regular expression so that non-keys don't match the regular expression in the first place.

```
fun2 <- function(x) if (!x %in% names(key)) sprintf("{%s}", x) else key[x]
gsubfn("{(\\w+)}", fun2, "{a} {others}")
## [1] "apple {others}"

key2 <- setNames(key, sprintf("{%s}", names(key))); 
gsubfn("{\\w+}", as.list(key2), "{a} {others}")
## [1] "apple {others}"

pat <- sprintf("{(%s)}", paste(names(key), collapse = "|"))
gsubfn(pat, as.list(key), "{a} {others}")
## [1] "apple {others}"
```

### Note

The inputs given in the question are:

```
txt <- "{a} is to {b} what {c} is to {d}"
key <- c(a='apple', b='banana', c='chair', d='door')
fun <- function(x) key[x]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `mgsub::mgsub`:

```r
names(key) <- paste0("\\{", names(key), "\\}")
mgsub::mgsub(txt, names(key), key)
#[1] "apple is to banana what chair is to door"
```